# Which verb form for helper in question?

Tags: grammar

I encountered the question, "Which trait does a savings account and a checking account have in common?" I suggested that it should read, "Which trait do a savings account and checking account have in common?" For which I was rebuffed. Shouldn't the helping verb *do* agree with the compound subject, the two accounts?

Answer (score 4):

Your understanding is correct. Consider the parallel construction

> Which date do Mike and Sally plan
>   to choose for their wedding?

No one in their right mind would insist it should be "Which date *does* Mike and Sally plan to choose for their wedding?"

Rearrange the words of your sentence and it becomes clearer:

> A savings account and [a] checking account
>   do have which trait in common?

It's never going to be:

> A savings account and [a] checking account
>   does have which trait in common?